# findOneAndRemove deletes wrong user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
router.delete('/user/:userId', (req ,res) => {   

    User.findOneAndRemove(req.params.userId, (err, doc) => {
        if(!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else {console.log('Error in Insurance agent Delete :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }

    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCRU.png)

Comment: Please post a question, not a fact.

Comment: do you pass the correct id?

Comment: when i pass any userid using postman it will delete a user with different userId

Comment: yes I pass the correct userId

Comment: see when I pass 962122961v it will delete 962122963v

Comment: @kentsteinwall, You are able to edit your question. Please provide more information in there. You don't have to send multiple comments on your own question.